# Extracting Wiki links using C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, string.h

I need to write a program that reads a Wikipedia  source file and extracts all the links to other webpages. All the webpages look like example:

```
<a href="/wiki/PageName" title="PageName">Chicken</a>
```

I basically need to match the PageName after /wiki/ with the title and if they are the same, as above, then display just the PageName on the terminal.

However, the following should not be matched since it is not in the same format as above: 
`<a href="http://chicken.com>Chicken</a>` (this is a link to a normal website off Wikipedia)
`<a href="/wiki/Chicken >Chicken</a`> (missing the title= section)
The output I am trying to achieve looks something like this:

[Example output I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jUyi.png)

I have worked on this for quite a while and have been able to do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE * file;
  file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  char line[512];
  char* search;

  while(!feof(file)){
    fgets(line,512,file);

    search = strstr( line, "<a href=\"/wiki/");

    if(search != NULL){
        puts(search);
    }
  }
}
```

The code only filters out till /wiki/ but I am blank from here onward. I have tried searching a lot but unable to get a lead. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You will get working code a lot faster using Perl or Python. C is not the best language for parsing strings. It's certainly possible, but it requires C knowledge.

Comment: @mvp part of a bigger project. Have to use C :(

Comment: `while(!feof(file))` [is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `while(!feof(file))` you can use `while(fgets(line,512,file))` and by adding couple of validations your final code with expected output will look like,

```
#ifdef  _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif //  MSC

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * file;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (!file)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    char line[512];
    char* search;

    while (fgets(line, 512, file)) {
        search = strstr(line, "<a href=\"/wiki/");

        if (search != NULL) {
            char *title = _strdup(search);
            if (title)
            {
                char* start = strstr(title, ">");
                char* end = strstr(start, "<");
                if (end)
                {
                    *end = 0;
                }
                if (strlen(start) >= 2)
                {
                    puts(start + 1);
                }
                free(title);
                title = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    file = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! Also do you know how i could further refine the search? To match with the required output?

Comment: @HadiZia I have added more code get expected output, hope that this will be helpful to you.

Comment: buddy i tried compiling the code but i got the following error, and i have no clue whats wrong. Help please :(       error: #endif without #if
#endif //  MSC
 ^
test.c:30:27: warning: implicit declaration of function '_strdup' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            char *title = _strdup(search);
                          ^
test.c:30:19: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'int'
      [-Wint-conversion]
            char *title = _strdup(search);
                  ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: You are using c99, so remove #ifndef (first 3 lines from code) replace _strdup with strdup. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: English_Wikipedia
Internet encyclopedia
Wikimedia Foundation
Jimmy Wales
protected page
Creative Commons Attribution/
English-language
the most articles of any of the editions
5,730,076
Simple English Wikipedia
Wikipedia:Milestones
dispute resolution
Dutch Wikipedia
Wikimedia Commons
Wikimedia Foundation
native language
Arbitration Committee
Jimmy Wales
arbitrators
German Wikipedia
Criticism of Wikipedia
Wikipedia Seigenthaler biography incident
Segmentation fault: 11
Okay so it gives some outputs!!!! but results in a segmentation fault at the end :(

Comment: @HadiZia which wiki page you are using?
Can you comment that url?

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t sz;
fseek(file, 0L , SEEK_END);
sz=ftell(file);
rewind(file);
char line[sz+1];
```

This will probably fix the segmentation fault.

Comment: @Mayur yes it fixed the seg fault started to print some extra links that do not match the pattern. But it still prints